# Changing the Windows 7 same folder file copy naming pattern?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

On my Windows 7 machine, when I make a copy (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V) of a file in the same folder I get the new file created with **" - Copy"** added to the file name:

1st copy: "foo.txt" -> "foo **- Copy**.txt".
2nd copy and so on: "foo.txt" -> "foo **- Copy (2)**.txt".

**Is there a way to change this naming pattern?**

Particularly I'm interested in changing the naming from " - Copy (index)" to "_index",
so that the files would be named foo_1.txt, foo_2.txt and so on.

I know there are 3rd party file managers that can do this, but I would like to know if there is a way to change this naming pattern in explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Without 3rd party software you can edit your registry to *some* effect (on Windows 8 and 10 too).

Add/edit the string value named **CopyNameTemplate** under:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates`

Whereas the default value data is *effectively* `%s - Copy`, you would want `%s_`.

Enumeration is handled separately so unfortunately you would still see "foo_ (2).txt" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I researched and find this answer :

> With Supercopier, use Ctrl + click/drag to copy files.
>
> [SuperCopier Website](http://supercopier.sfxteam.org/)
>
> In Supercopier's Confuguration settings, go to "Copies & moves behaviour", and in "Old file renaming pattern" type "" and in "New file renaming pattern" type "Copy of ".
>
> If you use just right-click and drag to make file copies, the context menu will give you the option to use Supercopier, but the default option is Windows' own copying.
>
> However, if you use Ctrl + click/drag, it uses Supercopier to copy, and the copy is named according to your preference. If a file is copied using Ctrl + click/drag to another directory, the renaming pattern is not used -- the customised renaming is used only on files copied to the same directory.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question - " I would like to know if there is a way to change this naming pattern in explorer."

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:

```
New-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates -Value "default value"
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates" -Name "CopyNameTemplate" -Value "%s - Copy"
```

Modify `- Copy` in the second command above according to your preference.

If the property already exists, use `Set-ItemProperty` instead of `New-ItemProperty`.

Tested on **Windows 10 22H2**.